# Core difference between SELinux and Apparmor

Tags: selinux, apparmor, lsm

What is the core [or kernel level] difference of `SELinux` and `Apparmor`?

Comment: Did you check https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/selinux-vs-apparmor-vs-grsecurity.html?

Comment: As i have mentioned in the question I wanted core or kernel level difference between them not pro's and con's. And Gresecurity is not even a security tools.

Comment: related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29378/comparison-between-apparmor-and-selinux

Answer (score 14):

AppArmor and SELinux are both independent [Linux security module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules) (LSM) implementations. They are configured using their own specific tools. Some distributions do ship with both kernel modules, but you can select only one at boot time ([stacking](https://lwn.net/Articles/635771/) certain other LSM modules, such as YAMA, is however possible).

A notable practical difference between the two systems is in how rules are applied. SELinux applies security labels to every object and access control rules are written for those labels. Additionally SELinux ships with a labeling database which maps paths with default file labels, creating a sort of path-based rule database. AppArmor rules work directly with paths.

SELinux at the moment contains more features which allow more fine grained or special access controls, such as [MLS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/mls) and [MCS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/sec-mcs-o). AppArmor at the moment also lacks [some](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/DevelopmentRoadmap#Towards_AppArmor_3.0) more basic features, such as support for fine grained networking rules.